# How to debug empty Vue errors?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am creating a Vue app, and every once in a while I get an error like this:

[image]

There is no error message. It's usually an error in my code, nothing too exotic.

Is there any kind of config I need to setup to have the actual error message?

Here is my stack:

- VueJS (latest version, new project)
- TypeScript
- Class components
- Project set up with vue-cli with Typescript, babel, nothing specific
- I run the project with `npm run serve`

Edit: I managed to fix the error: the AWS JS SDK was being called without having been configured. Fine, but why did I not get any error message?

Here was where the error was thrown in the AWS SDK:

```js
      if (!req.service.config.region && !req.service.isGlobalEndpoint) {
        req.response.error = AWS.util.error(new Error(),
          {code: 'ConfigError', message: 'Missing region in config'});
      }
```

Comment: Seeing the `AWS.util.error`'s first param `new Error()`, I think the AWS error might be storing its message in a non-standard way which Vue doesn't know how to read.
If that is correct, you would need a custom error handler to display them properly.